# Cropping in neural networks

Tags: neural-networks

The problem I am stuck with is in cropping tensors at certain parts of the network to obtain specific dimensions.

I am trying to construct the [U-net](https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/) convolutional neural network. Almost all of the components of this are well covered in the MMA neural network framework; the contraction part of the network was straightforward but the expansion path is more difficult.

At several locations in the network I need to crop a layer to match that of another in a different part of the network. For example, I need to concatenate a layer with dimensions {1,568,568} with another of dimensions {1,392,392} and need to match the dimensions of the two by cropping from the first.

`PaddingLayer` is close but (unlike `ArrayPad`) does not permit negative padding values, that is, something like `PaddingLayer[{-88,-88}]` would do the trick but it isn't possible. `ResizeLayer` is not the answer because it introduces some form of interpolation.

Is there some other way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PartLayer` is close, but it can only crop the first dimension. You can use `PartLayer` in combination with `TransposeLayer` to crop tensors:

```
data = {Table[i + j, {i, 10}, {j, 10}]};
Dimensions[data]
```

> {1, 10, 10}

```
NetChain[{TransposeLayer[3 -> 1],
   TransposeLayer[1 -> 2],
   PartLayer[2 ;; 3],
   TransposeLayer[1 -> 2],
   PartLayer[2 ;; 3],
   TransposeLayer[1 -> 3]}]@data
```

> {{{4.}, {5.}}, {{5.}, {6.}}}

Comment: That looks pretty close to what I needed (I should have looked more closely at PartLayer) thanks. Shouldn't the last TransposeLayer applied be `TransposeLayer[3->1]` (to get dimensions of {1,2,2}?

Comment: You're right, the result was transposed, should be fixed now. It would be more comfortable if `PartLayer` could take crop tensors they way `Part` does

Comment: I'll leave the post for a day or two in case another answer shows up before accepting

Comment: Just an FYI: `PartLayer` in 11.3 supports operation on any number of dimensions.

Comment: @NikiEstner can you kindly edit your answer to provide a minimal example in which you take outputs from two layers of a network and crop the first layer with regards to the dimensions of the second layer such that dimensions of first equals the second (of course we dont know the arguments to the PartLayer in advance). I dont know but your current answer shows that the arguments to the `PartLayer` need to be known. How can we implement it as a function keeping things symbolic? thanks !